# Create a REPL out of a command in bash

Tags: bash, read-eval-print-loop

Is there a way create a simple REPL out of a command?
I'm using `dc` calculator and the first part of the command is always `dc -e` and all that changes is the expression to be evaluated?

Comment: You want to build a simple loop that takes your input and calls `dc -e`with every single line?

Comment: dc has a REPL. Just run `dc`

Comment: @rici Oh. Didn't know. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote a tool that does just that:
https://github.com/mchav/with

It makes a script that wraps the command in a while loop. For example:

```
while true ; do
  while IFS="" read -r -e -d $'\n' -p '$1> ' options; do
    if [ "$options" = "quit" ]; then
     exit 0
    else
     "$1" "$options"
    fi
  done
done
```

Comment: The `-d $'\n'` is redundant; `read` stops reading at a newline by default.

Comment: Please explain what your code does. I don't want to copy paste it without knowing how it works.